# Stub is not returning the mocked recponse for QueryForParamater request

Tags: java, rest-assured, stub, wiremock

Trying to mock the QueryForparamater response but message as 'Request was not matched'. tried with below different ways but getting same result. Can anyone correct me to  unblock?

```
        ResponseDefinitionBuilder mockResponse1 = new ResponseDefinitionBuilder();
        mockResponse1.withStatus(201);
        mockResponse1.withBodyFile("pp/isOpenResponse.json");

        //WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(endpoint).withQueryParam("city",equalTo("1")).willReturn(mockResponse1));
       // WireMock.stubFor(get(endpoint+"?city=1 ").willReturn(mockResponse1));
        WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(endpoint+"?city=1 ").willReturn(mockResponse1));
        //WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(endpoint+"?city=1 ").willReturn(mockResponse1));
    
        startServer();
        String testapi= "http://localhost:8080"+endpoint;
        System.out.print("service to be hit :  "+testapi);

        Response mockResponse= RestAssured.given().queryParam("city","1").get(testapi).then().extract().response();
        System.out.println(mockResponse.prettyPrint());
```

Response on console is below

```
                               Request was not matched
                                               =======================

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
GET                                                        | GET
/readfromfile/index/?city=1                                | /readfromfile/index/?city=1                         <<<<< URL does not match
                                                           |
```

[image]

Comment: What did WireMock return when you tried `WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(endpoint).withQueryParam("city",equalTo("1")).willReturn(mockResponse1));`

Comment: Odd that `startServer();` is after you create the stubs - the server has to be running to create the stub. What is `startServer` doing? If it's restarting the WireMock server then your stub will be gone.